# Getting an unknown parse error with flot

Tags: flot

Can someone please point out what I'm missing here? I'm trying to generate a flot chart with the following function (which is called on success of the $.getJSON function in the page). At the moment, the chart is not loading at all and I get a parse error. If I removed this function, the parse error disappears, so I'm sure it's this function causing the problem but I can't see where!

```
function plotLineGraph(theData){
var myData = theData['data'];
var myDates = theData['dates'];
var d1 = [
          myData[0],  myData[1],  myData[2],  myData[3],  myData[4],
          myData[5],  myData[6],  myData[7],  myData[8],  myData[9],
          myData[10], myData[11], myData[12], myData[13], myData[14],
          myData[15], myData[16], myData[17], myData[18], myData[19],
          myData[20], myData[21], myData[22], myData[23], myData[24],
          myData[25], myData[26], myData[27], myData[28], myData[29]
          ];
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [
    {label: "rating",  data: d1}
    ], {
        series: {
            lines: { show: true },
            points: { show: true }
        },
        xaxis: {
            ticks:[
            myDates[0],  myDates[1],  myDates[2],  myDates[3],  myDates[4],
            myDates[5],  myDates[6],  myDates[7],  myDates[8],  myDates[9],
            myDates[10], myDates[11], myDates[12], myDates[13], myDates[14],
            myDates[15], myDates[16], myDates[17], myDates[18], myDates[19],
            myDates[20], myDates[21], myDates[22], myDates[23], myDates[24],
            myDates[25], myDates[26], myDates[27], myDates[28], myDates[29]
            ]
        },
        yaxis: {
            ticks: 5,
            min: 0,
            max: 5
        },
        grid: {
            backgroundColor: { colors: ["#fff", "#eee"] }
        }
});
}
```

EDIT:

The $.getJSON function returns the following JSON:

```
{
"data": [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0], [6, 0], [7, 0], [8, 0], [9, 0], [10, 0], [11, 0], [12, 0], [13, 0], [14, 0], [15, 0], [16, 0], [17, 0], [18, 0], [19, 0], [20, 0], [21, 0], [22, 0], [23, 3], [24, 3], [25, 2], [26, 0], [27, 0], [28, 0], [29, 0], [30, 0]],
"dates": [[1, '10/9'], [2, '11/9'], [3, '12/9'], [4, '13/9'], [5, '14/9'], [6, '15/9'], [7, '16/9'], [8, '17/9'], [9, '18/9'], [10, '19/9'], [11, '20/9'], [12, '21/9'], [13, '22/9'], [14, '23/9'], [15, '24/9'], [16, '25/9'], [17, '26/9'], [18, '27/9'], [19, '28/9'], [20, '29/9'], [21, '30/9'], [22, '1/10'], [23, '2/10'], [24, '3/10'], [25, '4/10'], [26, '5/10'], [27, '6/10'], [28, '7/10'], [29, '8/10'], [30, '9/10']]
}
```

EDIT 2:

Thanks Brendan. The call is here (it is part of a larger function which uses the same syntax to correctly generate a few other pie charts):

```
$.getJSON('/last-month-daily-average-for-products/' 
          + theProductUuid + '/', plotLineGraph);
```

As for the disassembling/reassembling of the JSON.... No particular reason, no. All I need to do is get the relevant data from the JSON into the correct parts of the flot function, so feel free to correct anything which is inefficient as well as incorrect!!

Comment: Can you show us your call and handling of the JSON data? IE, show us where you call plotLineGraph(theData).  

Also, is there any particular motivation for disassembling and re-assembling `myData` and `myDates` like you're doing?

Comment: @DNS and @ Brendan - For some reason, everything now seems to work fine. I ran through all possible troubleshooting before posting, but this morning, it seems to be 100% ok. Apologies for wasting your time. The error WAS a "parsererror"... The whole page is called using AJAX and although the page loads and the other JS functions work, the AJAX request returned "parsererror" via my AJAX setup configuration and the line graphs do not load. No error was reported in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with any of the code you have provided.  It works perfectly.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/eJ2h8/

Comment: Yup, Ryley, you're right. For some reason, this morning everything seems to be working for me as well. All I did in the interim was restart my computer..... Thanks very much for taking the time to put the jsfiddle together though. Out of interest, why did you call it "weird flot date code"...? I imagine there's a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do??

Comment: Flot supports a `time` mode where you can make your x values javascript timestamps.  That's the more normal way to do this type of graph.  You can see an [example](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/time.html) on the flot site.

Comment: Yes, thanks Ryley. We're certainly heading in that direction, but we're just building up the foundations of our app... There a quite a number of time-related functions which we'll need to deal with all at once.... Flot's representations of time will be one of them! Thanks for coming back though.